# combine 3 text from database to fill combobox

Tags: c#, jquery, combobox, xampp

i have 3 columns `fname = first name`, `mname = middle name` and `sname = surname` so i have to combine them to fill a single combo box

```
var query = "SELECT CONCAT(fname, ' ', mname, '', sname ) AS FullName FROM database.table;";


   using(MySqlConnection myConn = new MySqlConnection(ConnectionClass.GetConnection()))
 using(MySqlCommand cmDB = new MySqlCommand(query, myConn))
{
    try
    {
        myConn.Open();
        using(MySqlDataReader myReader = cmDB.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while(myReader.Read())
            {
                string FName = myReader.GetString("FullName");
                cmbName.Items.Add(FName);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        myConn.Close();
    }
}
```

i tried calling FullName a several time but it kept saying it cannot find the field so how do i do this?

Comment: string FName = (string)myReader[0];

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`FullName` is an alias rather than an existing filed name on your table, that's why `sqldatareder` cant recognize it. Try:

```
while(myReader.Read())
{
   string FName = myReader[0].ToString();
   cmbName.Items.Add(FName);
}
```

Comment: it work! thanks! but can you explain why myReader[0]?

Comment: 0 is the index of the first field of your select query (in ths case you only selct 1 field, so e.g. reader[1] will be out of bounds.